# React Application isn't using .jsx postfix when file name includes hypens

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have the following directory structure

```
src
 +actions
 +components
 +reducers
 +utils
 -views
  -app
   app-container.jsx
   app.jsx
   index.jsx
  -more-info
   index.js
   more-info-container.jsx
   more-info.jsx
  -overview
   index.jsx
   overview-container.jsx
   overview.jsx
```

Under `src/views/more-info`, if I try to update `index.js` to have the file extension `index.jsx` my build fails with `Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/smcclaine/Documents/Projects/ReactReduxBoilerPlate/src/views/more-info/index.js'`.

If I remove the hyphen from the directory structure and the import, it will then allow me to use the `.jsx` extension.

Anyone have any idea how to configure my application so it will use the `.jsx` if the directory has a hyphen in it?

**Git Repo:** https://github.com/sethimcclaine/SALT

Comment: With `node v8.9.4`, `npm 6.1.0` and file renamed from `src/views/more-info/index.js` to `src/views/more-info/index.jsx` I am able to build (`npm run build`) and access http://localhost:3000/more. What's your node and npm version and which command you use to build the application?

Comment: I tried changing the file name and then starting up my server and everything worked. It may have just be an issue with the build caching the location of the .js file and and not wanting to accept the .jsx until the server is restarted.

Thanks for giving it a shot @PatrykWojtasik